# RabbitMQ Fanout Exchange (VirtualTopic Equivalent)

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I'm looking at swapping out ActiveMQ with RabbitMQ for a few reasons. I currently have multiple services which are each capable of publishing events (and they publish those events to a specific VirtualTopic in AMQ). Each of the services is also capable of consuming messages from the other services. Consumers are set up such that they subscribe as a consumer to a queue on the VirtualTopic.

This buys me the ability to fan messages out to multiple queues (topic-like functionality) while keeping the benefits of queues (load balancing and persistence).

It seems like this is roughly equivalent to RabbitMQ's fanout exchange. However, the part that I found very useful in ActiveMQ is that the producer doesn't need to have any knowledge of the consumers. It simply publishes to the virtual topic. It seems that in RabbitMQ, when the exchange is created, I need a definitive of queues to publish that message to.

**tl;dr**

Is there any routing scheme in RabbitMQ that is equivalent to ActiveMQ's Virtual Topic, such that I can produce messages to a topic that are distributed to any queue that has been created off of that Virtual Topic, without requiring a hard-coded routing scheme somewhere in RMQ?

Comment: as a side comment, could you explain why you are migrating from ActiveMQ to RabbitMQ? I'm considering going in the other direction, mainly to be able to use AWS managed ActiveMQ instances, and I'd love to know if you suffered with ActiveMQ in any way.

Comment: ActiveMQ's operational burden vastly outweighed its utility. We weren't using a significant component of what ActiveMQ offered, and it's much more painful to handle replication/clustering in ActiveMQ. Plus, we had been bitten in the past by unexplained maintenance nightmares. Honestly, I'm sure it has come a long way, and I'm sure AWS' offering is more stable than what we could provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized after posting this question that it is pretty trivial to do this (not sure why I never thought of it before).

I was looking at it from the wrong direction, wondering how I could automatically have the publisher configure queues for the recipients - which isn't the right way to approach this question.

Instead, I have the subscribers, when they start up, bind themselves to the exchange that the publisher users, which provides in the inversion of control I'm looking for (publishers need not know anything about their consumers).

Comment: I've wondered about the RabbitMQ equivalent of a `Topic` in ActiveMQ and still have not gotten my arms around how a `Fanout Exchange` does the same thing. In ActiveMQ, a `Topic` can have multiple subscribers. In RabbitMQ, a `Fanout Exchange` can broadcast to multiple queues. But if any of those receiving queues had multiple consumers, then only one of those consumers can get the message from that queue. Does that mean that a `Fanout Exchange` works like a true `Topic` only when each queue is consumed by exactly one consumer/subscriber?

Comment: In the RabbitMQ Fanout exchange, the exchange itself can be treated as a topic. Any message published to fanout exchange (topic) is routed to multiple connected subscribers through the queues